# R: sub_group counter which resets by one of two grouping variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this tibble of sample data:

```
library(tibble)

data <- tibble(
  cat_1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  cat_2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6)
)
```

And I would like to create a third column, for instance named `reset_grp_marker` as follows:

```
result <- tibble(
  cat_1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  cat_2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6),
  reset_grp_marker = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
)

   cat_1 cat_2 reset_grp_marker
   <chr> <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 A         1                1
 2 A         1                1
 3 A         2                2
 4 A         2                2
 5 B         3                1
 6 B         4                2
 7 B         4                2
 8 C         5                1
 9 C         5                1
10 C         5                1
```

In words: `reset_grp_marker` counts the sub_groups as defined by `cat_2` for each main group `cat_1`. However, when `cat_1` moves to the next main group, `reset_grp_marker` resets to 1. In the sample data shown, when `cat_1` changes from `A` to `B`, `reset_grp_marker` resets to 1. And so on.

My real-world data object contains hundreds of `cat_1` values which each `cat_1` group containing hundreds of lines. `cat_2`can contain dozen or so different values. 
Either `baseR` or `tydiverse` solutions requested.

Looks easy....and probably is.

Comment: `data %>%
  group_by(cat_1) %>%
  mutate(reset_grp_marker = match(cat_2, unique(cat_2)))` and other options in marked link.

Comment: Much appreciated Ronak! Clean & simple.